# How do chain commands in Scala interpreter?

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

In windows batch, you [chain commands with && operator](https://www.google.ee/search?q=command%20line%20command%20chaining). How do you do the same in scala interpreter? It looks stupid that I need `:load file` and call `import mainobj._` after every load. Obviously, you want to chain them into one liner.

Comment: You could do `sbt console` with a build.sbt file which automatically runs your commands

Answer (score 0):

You could write multiple statements in one line of Scala with `;`

```
scala> val a:Int = 3; val b:Int = 4; println(a+b);
7
a: Int = 3
b: Int = 4
```

Or first type `{` then write your commands line by line finishing with `}`

```
scala> {
     | val x:Int = 1
     | val y:Int = 2
     | println(x + y)
     | }
3
```

Or you can use `:paste` to turn on paste mode, and then enter your code.

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

if (true)
  print("that was true")
else
  print("false")

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

that was true
```

Comment: That does not work for `:load file` as in the question.

Comment: The question is asking for an alternative to `:load file`

Comment: I would disagree. And copy and pasting the file's contents into paste mode is supposed to be better than `:load`? You at least don't have to always open up the file and copy it's contents. I don't think it can be done in a nicer way than doing `:load file` and `import ...` separately.

Comment: @AkosKrivachy an opinion isn't an answer. The user was asking how to chain commands. This answers that question. We aren't concerned if chaining commands is better or worse, just how it can be achieved.

Comment: No, the user was asking how to chain a REPL command (in this case: `:load file`) with a line of Scala code (`import ...`). So I still believe this answer answers a different and more general question, because this only shows how to chain Scala code and not REPL commands.

Comment: This workaround is more terrible than doing :load and import separately. Might be somebody can be happy with it but I demand a better one.